# How are 'numpy.reshape' and 'ndarray.reshape' equivalent?

Tags: python, numpy, reshape

I have a question about the structure of `ndarray.reshape`. I have read that `numpy.reshape()` and `ndarray.reshape` are equivalent commands in python to reshape an array.

As far as I know, numpy is an *Object* in which the `reshape` *method* is defined. So the usage of the dot operator in `numpy.reshape()` is understandable for me. But when it comes to `ndarray.reshape`, I don't understand how the dot operator works. There is no reference to the *numpy* object in `ndarray.reshape`; how does it know that `reshape` is related to the numpy object?

Comment: In `numpy.reshape`, `reshape` is a function in the `numpy` module.  In `arr.reshape` (where `arr` is a `numpy.ndarray`), `reshape` is method of the `ndarray` class.  Technically both uses of the `dot` define a namespace, but the distinction between function and method is basic to Python.

Comment: Thanks for the useful information.
Consider: `b=np.arange(6).reshape(3,2)`. 
So, in this line, the `np.arange(6)` part create an object that is fed into the next method  `reshape(3,2)`?

Comment: yes. `arange` is a function in `np` module.,  `reshape` is a method of the object created by that `arange` call.  The result is a new array object. which is assigned to `b`.

Answer (score 3):

I might be understanding something wrong, but usually `numpy` refers to the actual Numpy module, and by calling `numpy.reshape` you are calling the static function and you also need to pass the array into it as the first argument, whereas the `ndarray` bit defers to an actual numpy-array.
Example:

```
# import the module here
import numpy

# create an vector of 9 elements
arr = numpy.random.rand(1,9)

# and now I call the 'static' version of the reshape method:
arr2 = numpy.reshape(arr, (3,3))

# and here I just call the reshape method of the existing array
arr3 = arr.reshape((3,3))
```

Essentially, these last two lines of code are equivalent, so the `arr2` and `arr3` contain the same 3x3 array.